# Getting NS_ERROR_FAILURE when loading a large image in Firefox for WebGL2 3D texture

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-canvas, webgl, webgl2

My texture loading approach is working fine in Chrome or Opera but I got a problem only with Firefox. I am using WebGL2 and loading a 3D texture in a form of one big image where the layers are stored one after another. When I run this simplified example:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() 
    {   
        var temp = document.createElement('canvas');
        temp.width = 1280;
        temp.height = 720 * 64;
        var tempCtx = temp.getContext('2d');
        tempCtx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        // The problem is with the line below
        var data = new Uint8Array(tempCtx.getImageData(0, 0, temp.width, temp.height).data.buffer);
        console.log("loaded");  
    };
    image.src = "test.png"; 
}
</script>
```

The image is loading but then I get an error:

```
Uncaught NS_ERROR_FAILURE: onload <here is a reference to the marked line in the code above>
```

I have no idea what is wrong. The code is called after all GL initialization and shader compilations but it does not seem to be related to WebGL at all. Any advice is much appreciated!

After some experiments I noticed, that smaller images can be loaded. Is this some kind of a memory limit in Firefox? The image I need is indeed pretty large. I tried to edit `dom.max_script_run_time` and `image.cache.size` in `about:config` but no luck.

Comment: Please provide more information about the error.

Comment: @LajosArpad There is nothing more in the console. That's what confuses me even more.

Comment: Can you provide some information about the reference to the marked line?

Comment: @LajosArpad It's just the path to the file and line number. No extra information.

Comment: How are you hosting the files? Could be a cross origin related issue.

Comment: @LajosArpad The files are on the same domain. The texture is quite large, maybe Firefox has some limitations for image loading? The WebGL report site shows the same limits as other browsers though.
EDIT: I tried a smaller image and it seems to work.

Comment: how large is it exactly?

Comment: @LJᛃ I've updated the example. It's 1280 x (720 * 64) as the texture is HD image of 64 layers.

Comment: Maybe check `MAX_3D_TEXTURE_SIZE` and `MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS`

Comment: @LJᛃ I did that but the problem seems to be with the image even before GL stuff. I removed the GL code form the example and still the same problem.

Comment: @LJᛃ Thanks for your help! I solved the issue, Firefox has some limits that can be changed apparently. Your questions kind of guided me to the right track!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Firefox is more strict regarding memory usage. There are limits set for the texture and canvas size. There are several solutions:

1. Split the textures to more smaller ones and load them one by one
2. Make sure that the input images are at the minimal format, e.g., for PNG that it is RGB8 for standard non-transparent image and not, e.g., RGBA16
3. Adjust the browser settings - type `about:config` to the address, hit enter, Accept the Risk and Continue, type `gfx.canvas.max-size` to the search bar and change its value to the one you need or maximal (2147483647) if you're not sure, do the same with `gfx.max-texture-size`, restart Firefox

This solved my issue!